# Private Docker Registry (with TLS certificate)

Tags: ssl, tls, docker-registry

I'm trying to setup a private docker registry based on the documentation of https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#running-a-domain-registry.

I'm using StartSSL as certificate issuer, downloaded their intermediate crt's and combined them with my client certificate:

```
cd certs    
cat sca.server3.crt ca.crt client.pem  > client.crt
```

After starting the registry with

```
docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 --name registry -v `pwd`/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/client.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/private.key registry:2
```

the registry complains about mismatching private/public key. However the very same certificate + private key works in some other Apache site.
I didn't get that error before I had added the intermediate crt's to the client.crt

```
time="2016-07-18T11:34:19Z" level=fatal msg="crypto/tls: private key does not match public key"
```

As the registry is running inside an intranet (not public internet) I don't want to setup an apache/nginx just to act as proxy.

Sidenote: I'm using Docker Mac (Docker version 1.12.0-rc4, build e4a0dbc, experimental).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remeber the **order** on how you combine your certificates is important.

try the bottom up approach:

`cat domain.crt intermediate-certificates.pem ca.pem > chained-domain.crt`

Comment: can also use https://certificatechain.io/ to help build the chain properly. Hasn't done me wrong yet!